# LED brightness control using PWM according to temperature of RTD/PTC/NTC thermistor

Tags: led, sensor, pwm, temperature

I am working on this project. Everything is going okay; I am generating PWM using a 74HC14 IC and I have used a potentiometer to vary the brightness of LEDs until now. The actual problem arises when it comes to generate PWM and vary the brightness according to temperature of any temperature sensors I have mentioned above. Any insight would be appreciated. A circuit diagram of the same is welcome. And where do we find the application of the same??

My current circuit is: -

[image]

Comment: the basic idea here is that the temperature changes will change the resistance and this will work same as potentiometer. So i think , instead of potentiometre we have to use the RTD/PTC. But am not able to incorporate the same in my project.

Comment: What circuit can you show us? Post it anywhere retrievable (by a link) and someone with enough reputation will embed it into your question.

Comment: http://www.robotroom.com/PWM.html

Comment: here is the circuit of the same

Answer (score 1):

I think if you replaced R2 with two thermistors in series; one with positive temperature coefficient and one with negative temperature coefficient this might work.

The centre point of the two thermistors would connect where the pot wiper currently goes.

You might find that you need to swap the positions of the two thermistors in case the opposite effect happens.